# service fabric background job - stateless

Tags: azure, background, jobs, azure-service-fabric

I m planning to host the the many job in serice fabric as stateless service run asyc. plan is to host on the multiple nodes and them running in parallel with the que mechanism. The only issue (may be) if I follow the design with multiple jobs, running on many node , running same time hitting the same database, could cause a database issue?. In typical on prem application, it used to be SQL queue, so SQL could read the message and process them. But in this scenario, the service fabric nodes it self instructing the database may cause slowness at the DB level.

Does anyone has faced the issue? or deployed background run asyc process on all SF nodes running parallel for data concentric work?

Comment: Before I can give you a good answer I need to know abit more about the nature of the jobs.

What's the average run time for each?

Do they need to run in sequal?
Are they naturaly grouped in some way?

Comment: Yes,  they could run in parallel.  I tried deploying it with all nodes with the batching approach in controlled way, it seems good so far. Thanks for the response.

Comment: I have a use case similar to yours. what do you mean by _deploying it with all nodes with the **batching approach in a controlled way**_